# Heap Memory default allocation in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, jvm, datastax

As per cassandra-env.sh the default heap memory allocation for a 440G Total RAM should be 32765M (Maximum CAP before JVM Swithches to 64 bit reference).

So, why is it showing 32210157568 bytes(30718M) when I query "java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version" or "java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'MaxHeapSize'"

Why is there difference, of around 2G.

*FYI: jvm.options files was default & using DSE 5.1.3.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` has nothing to do with Cassandra, and I don't know why you mention `cassandra-env.sh`. Anyway, let me answer the main part of the question.

In JDK 8, when `-Xmx` is not specified, the maximum heap size is estimated as

```
MaxHeapSize = min(1/4 RAM, max_heap_for_compressed_oops)
```

In your case the server has plently of RAM, so the default heap size is limited by the maximum possible size supported by zero-based compressed oops, that is, 32 GB.

The heap obviously cannot start at zero address (null page is reserved by the OS), and the [default heap alignment](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/bfac16f18d92/src/share/vm/memory/collectorPolicy.cpp#l174) is 2 MB, so we must subtract at least 2 MB.

Then, JDK prefers to allocate the heap at `HeapBaseMinAddress`, which is [equal to 2 GB](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/bfac16f18d92/src/os_cpu/linux_x86/vm/globals_linux_x86.hpp#l47) on Linux. This provides some space to grow the native heap of the process. For this reason JVM [reduces](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/bfac16f18d92/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l1844) the default maximum heap size by `HeapBaseMinAddress`.

That's why the final computed heap size is equal to

```
32 GB - 2 MB - 2 GB = 32210157568
```

If you give up the requirement for the zero-based compressed oops, you may set `-XX:HeapBaseMinAddress=0`. In this case the computed heap size would be

```
32 GB - 2MB = 32766 MB
```

Comment: I used Cassandra because, Cassandra runs under JVM, So there is a file called cassandra-env.sh where it says, the MAX_HEAP_SIZE is calculated based on "max(min(1/2 ram, 1024MB), min(1/4 ram, 32GB))" and a comment saying "# cap here to 32765M because the JVM switches to 64 bit references at 32767M" and pointing to link " http://java-performance.info/over-32g-heap-java/"

Comment: @apangin why is there still 2MB subtracted from the heap size when its start address isn’t anywhere near the zero address?

Comment: @Pramod Apparently the comment in `cassandra-env.sh` is wrong (at least, for the modern JDK versions). You may sumbit the issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CASSANDRA

Comment: @Holger The code computing the limits simply discounts the null page [first](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/bfac16f18d92/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l1841), and adjusts the size for the HeapBaseMinAddress [afterwards](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/bfac16f18d92/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l1843). You're right, it does not need to be like this, but such optimization does not make much value anyway.

Comment: @apangin well, yes, it doesn’t take much away in this case. But I’m a bit surprised whenever I notice such short-sighted code in the JVM. E.g., the code that is responsible for the array size limitation is really strange and doesn’t even have a justification for its existence…